# How can I tell the browser to empty a field by using JQuery and then call the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inserted a form on a html page, which contains several fields the user is supposed to fill ("name", "surname", a textarea, and so on); I then added a button and assigned the id *Click* to it:

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="Click" id="cliccami">
```

I linked the html page to a JQuery file.
By using JQuery I want to add a function *clearAll* which clears all the fields in the form when the user clicks on the button. I want to use another function *main* which calls the function *clearAll* when the button is clicked, as in the following:

```
function main() {
    $("form").on("button", clearAll);
}
```

How can I write the function clearAll (to empty the fields in the form) by using JQuery?

Comment: The same way you wrote the `main()` one? Or do you mean you don't know how to clear the fields with jQuery?

Comment: `:input` will select all elements that are form inputs.  You can use that, paired with filtering out buttons and submits, and set their value to blank, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function you can target the `closest()` form of `this` element to `find` all the elements to clear them like the following way:

```
function main() {
  $("form").on("click", "#cliccami", clearAll);
}

function clearAll() {
  $(this).closest("form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
}
```

```js
function main() {
  $("form").on("click", "#cliccami", clearAll);
}
main();
function clearAll() {
  $(this).closest("form").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Comments:</label>
    <textarea id="comments"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" id="cliccami">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `.val()` function to set the value of a input element. Check the snippet for an example:

```js
function clearAll() {
  $(":input[type=text]").val("");
}

function main() {
    $("#cliccami").on("click", clearAll);
}

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">

<input type="button" name="button" value="Click" id="cliccami">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your function using the onclick attribute. And use reset method to reset the entire form this way.

```js
function main(){
  // reset form
  $('#my-form')[0].reset();
  // do whatever you want
  alert('Form cleared!');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form id="my-form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="main()" class="btn btn-default">Clear All</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<form id="form1" action="">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Click" id="cliccami">
</form>
```

```js
function clearAll() {
  $('#form1 input, #form1  textarea, #form1  select').each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
}

$("#cliccami").on('click',function(){
    clearAll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#clearit').click(function(){
  $(":input[type=text]").val("");
  setTimeout(function(){ afteremptyfield();  }, 1000);
})
function afteremptyfield(){
alert("Function trigged after clearing fields")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">

<input type="button" name="button" value="Clear and trigger a function" id="clearit">
```

**This is how it could be done....**